# My push constants incorrect are passed to the shader

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I draw 3 triangles and want to use push constants to pass the matrix and color.
Here is the data structure that I want to pass:

```
struct MatrixesPushConstants
{
    glm::mat4 MVPmatrix;
    glm::vec3 vertexColors[3];
};
MatrixesPushConstants pushConstants[3];
```

And I want the third triangle to be completely white

```
pushConstants[2].MVPmatrix = base_camera.matrices.perspective * base_camera.matrices.view * transform;
pushConstants[2].vertexColors[0] = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
pushConstants[2].vertexColors[1] = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
pushConstants[2].vertexColors[2] = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

I'm specify one push constants range

```
VkPushConstantRange pushConstantRange{};
pushConstantRange.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
pushConstantRange.offset = 0;
pushConstantRange.size = sizeof(MatrixesPushConstants); //100
```

And I specify it in the Pipeline Layout

```
VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo{};
pipelineLayoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 1;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pPushConstantRanges = &pushConstantRange;
```

And I draw three triangles

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    vkCmdPushConstants(commandBuffer, pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0, sizeof(MatrixesPushConstants), &pushConstants[i]);
    vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

For all triangles the matrices are transferred correctly, but there are problems with the colors.
Pay attention to the third triangle (right), but it should be white.

Vertex shader

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inColor;

layout(push_constant) uniform MatrixesPushConstants
{
    mat4 MVPmatrix;
    vec3 vertexColors[3];
} pushConstants;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = pushConstants.MVPmatrix * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    fragColor = pushConstants.vertexColors[gl_VertexIndex];
}
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);
}
```

[image]

Here is what information I get about renderdoc, in this case it is clear that the third element in the array of colors is incorrectly transmitted.

[image]

I've tried using `alignas(16)`, but it doesn't help

```
struct MatrixesPushConstants
{
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 MVPmatrix;
    alignas(16) glm::vec3 vertexColors[3];
};
```

Comment: I'd have to check the spec, but it looks like the GPU is expecting your vec3's to have a 16 byte alignment.

Comment: @vandench, I've tried using `alignas(16)`, but it doesn't help

Comment: @vandench, Yes, you're right. The problem is alignment, if I use vec4 instead of vec3 in the structure, then everything works as it should. Thanks!